# How to resolve MongoDb error with nested schemas?

Tags: database, mongodb, deployment, server, schema

```
TypeError: Undefined type `Map` at `expensesByCategory`
    Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.
      at Schema.interpretAsType (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:673:11)
      at Schema.path (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:529:29)
      at Schema.add (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:411:12)
      at new Schema (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:105:10)
      at file:///app/models/KPI.js:51:19
      at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)
```

I'm getting this error when trying to deploy my application on fly.io.

This is the schema I'm using

```
const KPISchema = new Schema(
  {
    totalProfit: {
      type: mongoose.Types.Currency,
      currency: "USD",
      get: (v) => v / 100,
    },
    totalRevenue: {
      type: mongoose.Types.Currency,
      currency: "USD",
      get: (v) => v / 100,
    },
    totalExpenses: {
      type: mongoose.Types.Currency,
      currency: "USD",
      get: (v) => v / 100,
    },
    expensesByCategory: {
      type: Map,
      of: {
        type: mongoose.Types.Currency,
        currency: "USD",
        get: (v) => v / 100,
      },
    },
    monthlyData: [monthSchema],
    dailyData: [daySchema],
  },
  { timestamps: true, toJSON: { getters: true } }
);
```

Since I'm new to MongoDb can you suggest ways to resolve this issue. I understand that the issue with the nested schema. Is there a way to resolve this without changing the behaviour of the schema.

Comment: What do you mean by *"without changing the behaviour of the schema."*?

Comment: As in is there a way to fix the error by changing the format of the schema without disrupting the intended functionality of the schema.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking what version of mongoose you using in your package.json.

I updated mongoose from

`"mongoose": "^4.13.21"`

to

`"mongoose": "^7.0.0"`

And ran `npm install` and this resolved the issue. You'll get a peer dependency warning - which appears to be due to mongoose-currency and the fact that it has not been updated in quite some time, and possibly shouldn't be used in production.

I ran into this same error and found your post when trying to solve it, this is what worked for me.